# Borrar/subir proyectos a git hub

Tags: github

Tengo un problema en github que no tengo claro cómo solucionarlo ya que soy novato en el tema repositorios.
Resulta que subí un proyecto a un repositorio remoto desde mi repositorio local. Ahora necesito borrar lo que hay en el repositorio remoto para dejarlo vacío y subir un nuevo proyecto a el desde mi local, no tengo muy claro cómo hacerlo, ya que hice un init en mi nuevo proyecto para crear un nuevo repositorio para enlazarlo con el remoto , borrar lo que hay en remoto y subir lo que tengo en local. 
¿cómo se haría esto? es decir los comandos a seguir en la consola cmd de windows para poder realizar dicha operación.

Gracias

Comment: Soy bastante novato también en Github, pero creo que lo mas fácil es entrar a Github (desde el navegador), y eliminarlos desde ahí. Saludos,

Comment: el problema es que para eliminarlo desde el navegador tengo que ir fichero a fichero y son cientos de ficheros :(

Comment: Lo más práctico sería que borres el repositorio desde la página de GitHub, para hacerlo seleccionas el repositorio, vas a Settings y casi al final de la página verás la Danger Zone. ahí podrás usar la opción Delete. Posteriormente realiza un pull en el cliente, verás que ya no existe el repositorio, entonces podrás crear un repositorio con el mismo nombre pero con el contenido que quieres asignar dentro.

Answer (score 1):

**Método 1:**

Ingresa a tu proyecto en github:

```
https://github.com/miusuario/miproyecto
```

Ingresa al final de "Settings" según muestra la imagen y pulsa el botón "Delete this repository":
[image: Delete this Repository]

Una vez eliminado el proyecto de github, créalo nuevamente (puede ser con el mismo nombre):

```
https://github.com/new
```

Ve a la carpeta donde esta tu repositorio local y elimina la carpeta ".git". Esta carpeta esta oculta. En Linux la puedes ver con CTRL + H. En Windows marcando la opción "Mostrar archivos ocultos"

Ahora resta enlazar el repositorio local con el de github y subir los archivos. Ejemplo:

```
cd /home/user/miproyecto/
git config --global user.name "miusuario"
git config --global user.email "micorreo@gmail.com"
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Lo que quieras poner"
git push -f origin master
```

**Método 2:**

El segundo método consiste en reubicar el repositorio. La explicación detallada, paso a paso, la puedes encontrar en el post "[Github: This repository moved. Please use the new location](https://www.maravento.com/2016/07/github-this-repository-moved-please-use.html)"

Answer (score 0):

Para eliminar todos los archivos del repositorio, primero deberás eliminar de tu carpeta local todo aquello que ya no quieres que esté y después sincronizarlo con tu repositorio en github.

Los pasos:

1. Borras todo lo que ya no quieres que esté en el repositorio de tu proyecto en la carpeta local.
2. Vas a la consola, te situas en el directorio donde está tu proyecto.
3. Escribes:

   `git add *` (con esto estás agregando o quitando todo lo de tu carpeta al repositorio de github)

   `git commit -m 'borrando archivos ya no usados'` (le indicas que vas a borrar los archivos)

   `git push origin master` (subes los cambios a la rama master)

Y con eso ya estaría, ahora los archivos que hayas eliminado en tu carpeta local, tampoco estarán en tu repositorio de github.

Comment: y si es en otra rama que no es la master hago el último paso con el nombre de la rama en vez de master no?

Comment: exacto, sólo tienes que cambiar master, por el nombre de tu rama